# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1, only when testing on device

Tags: ios, linker

I was just about to test my app on a device when I ran into this problem, I'm getting this Linker Error.
I've already checked all my compile sources and Build Phases, but there's no sign of my importing things twice.

> ld: duplicate symbol _calculateNextSearchPage in /Users/wouter/Sites/test/FastPdfKit.embeddedframework/FastPdfKit.framework/FastPdfKit(FastPdfKit) and /Users/wouter/Sites/test/FastPdfKit.embeddedframework/FastPdfKit.framework/FastPdfKit(FastPdfKit) for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This only happens when testing on a device, not in the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

Alright guys I had the same problem. Seems like I fixed it. 
I am using cocapods therefor the described standard procedure can not be properly executed.

**Steps to do to properly add FastPDFKit with Cocoapods.**

- Download FastPDFKit
- In your project Add Files to "Your Project"
- go to FastPDFKit folder you just have downloaded
- locate 1 folder and 1 project file. Press and hold Command key and add these in to your project
- `FastPdfKit.xcodeproj`
- `FastPdfKit.embeddedframework`

[image]

*(Note: `FastPdfKit.embeddedframework` is the actual Framework and you
   might want to open FastPdfKit.xcodeproj standalone before adding it
   to your project, delete  FastPdfKit.embeddedframework folder from
   your disk and Build FastPdfKit target in the project. You should see
   newly created `FastPdfKit.embeddedframework` folder)*

- Go to your Project Settings > Your target > Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries
- Make sure FastPdfKit.framework is there.
- If not, drag it from the project and put it there.
- Clean the project, delete derived data
- Add `#import <FastPdfKit/FastPdfKit.h>` where you need it and you are good to go.
- Here is how my Link Binary with  Libraries look like

  [image]

Please let me know if you have any troubles I might've missed something.

Comment: Thanks a lot. worked perfectly. The only thing i was struggling was that i didn't add all frameworks needed for fastpdfkit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete duplicate files/images which are in target-> Build phase -> Compile files, Copy bundle resources

Comment: That's the problem, there are no duplicate files or images, already checked that multiple times.